# Promise returning unexpected result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I'm quite new to promises and use state but I have been looking at this for hours and i can't understand what the issue here but it may be my understanding of promises. Any help would be appreciated.

I have a component that is hydrated with props from a response api:

```
const [trafficData, setTrafficData] = useState();

getTrafficDetails().then(r => {
    setTrafficData(r);
})

<TrafficWidget incomingData={trafficData} />
```

traffic widget component

```
const TrafficWidgetComponent = (data) => {
    let [trafficDetails, setTrafficDetails] = useState(null);

    if(data){
      const toShow = data.map((item) => {
        //return some jsx
        return(<div>{item.roadName}: {item.trafficCondition}</div>)
      })

      setTrafficDetails(toShow);
    }

    return(<>{toShow}</>)
}
```

The method for the api returned in a promise which is consumed by my app is here:

```
const getTrafficDetails = (linkOne, linkTwo) => {
  const a = fetch(linkOne)
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then((data) => data.TRAFFIC_INFO);
  const b = fetch(linkTwo)
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then((data) => data.TRAFFIC_INFO);
  return Promise.all([a, b]).then((td) => {
    const copiedData = [...td]
    //do something with copiedData to combine all objects into array of objects and add new properties
    return combineAndAddMetadata(copiedData)
  });
};
```

combineAndAddMetadata

```
const combineAndAddMetadata = (trafficData) => {
  const combinedTrafficObject = [].concat(...trafficData);
  const toReturn = [];

  combinedTrafficObject.map((trafficDataItem) => {
    const { id, cotwoEmissions, utl } = trafficDataItem;

    const filteredObject = toReturn.find((item) => item.id === id);

    if (!filteredObject) {
      trafficDataItem.totalEmission = currencyFormatter(cotwoEmissions * utl);
      toReturn.push(trafficDataItem);
    } else {

      const totalCSL = cotwoEmissions * filteredObject.utl;

      filteredObject.utl += utl;
      filteredObject.totalEmission = totalCSL;
      filteredObject.totalEmissionFormatted = currencyFormatter(totalCSL);
    }
  });
```

the data that comes back from this method is an array of objects: `[{...}, {...}, etc]` which I can see in the console.

What I can't understand is why the variable from the callback, the `td` on the .then in `getTrafficDetails` is now updated with the new metadata even though I copied it.

Even weirder, when i inspect the data going into the `TrafficWidget` component from this method, it transforms into an object with the requested data inside it, with strangely with length 0, in the form of `{data: [{},{}]}` which if i then access in the TrafficWidget component via `data.data`, causes an infinite loop which causes a crash. (although logging `r` before setting `trafficData` shows the correct data in the correct format)

Can anyone shed some light on this?

**edit**: added response that I receive from the fetch and what i'm trying to end up with

eg data coming from fetch url 1:

```
[{id: '000', cotwoEmissions: 345, utl: 45},{id: '001', cotwoEmissions: 345, utl: 34}]
```

e.g. data coming from fetch url 2:

```
[{id: '000', cotwoEmissions: 345, utl: 32},{id: '003', cotwoEmissions: 345, utl: 45} ]
```

what i try and do in the merge is have an array of objects which combine these where the id is the same and where they are the same, the utl values are combined and multiplied by the cotwoEmissions value (which are the same for a given id). I then add some extra properties to each object based on this and return a new array with all of the objects.

so the above, as an output would become:

```
[{id: '000', cotwoEmissions: 345, utl: 77, totalEmission: 26,565, totalEmissionFormatted: '26,565'},{id: '001', cotwoEmissions: 345, utl: 1, totalEmission: 345, totalEmissionFormatted: '345'}, {id: '003', cotwoEmissions: 100, utl: 2, totalEmission: 200, totalEmissionFormatted: '200'}]
```

Comment: You're only doing a shallow copy of td, so if the items inside td change, the items inside copiedData will change as well. Is there something that would change that data in memory? If so, likely you'll need a deep copy instead.

Comment: Not enough real code shown here to follow what's actually happening.  Since you say you have the data you want in `td`, but then you don't have what you want later, we need to see all the relevant code in between where you are copying/transforming that data.  That is likely where the problem is.

Comment: And, why are you doing double `data.json()` calls?

Comment: @jfriend00 that was a typo during formatting, resolved - also added the relevant code inbetween

Comment: It sure would help if we could see what data you start with and what you want the result to be after modifying.  As others have said, you are probably doing a shallow copy which isn't a complete copy so you retain references to common objects and when you modify those objects they still point to the originals so you see the changes in the originals too.  But, without seeing the actual data, we can't really know for sure.

Comment: @jfriend00 added a description of response and expected outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't answer for all the strangeness but inside your transformation function, you first destruct the trafficData item but then also modify it. This will modify the td variable as well since it keeps a reference to the same items.

What you likely want is to instead create a new object with the modified values and old values (that you destructured) and add that newly created item into toReturn instead.

This is good practice in general to avoid confusion like this, don't modify input parameters, instead copy and return a new object on each level if something has actually changed.
This is mostly for the case of when you don't find the filteredObject (the first time you modify an item), when you find the object you know that the object you found is an object you've created inside this function (assuming you modify your code to create a new object to push into toReturn) so it should be safe to modify again.

Comment: Thanks @Milton, it seems that I had a misunderstanding as to how the spread operator copies complex objects! I didn't realise it was just a shallow copy!